# List<T> is non nullable?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Using VS 2022, .Net 6.0, I thought this was correct :

```
public static void test(List<String> list = null)
{ }
```

but compiler warns me :

> ```
> CS8625 Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type
> ```

`List<T>` should be nullable by definition, right?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, rereading it again more carefully indeed point out : `Starting in .NET 6, they're [Null-state analysis and variable annotations] enabled by default for new projects.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently, Microsoft enabled nullable reference types by default on new projects.

You have five ways to make this warning go away:

1. You can respect nullable reference types, and change the type of your parameter:

```
public static void test(List<String>? list = null) { }
```

2. You can ignore the null assignment using the `!` operator. (I like to call this the "I know better" operator because I will typically use it when I know what I'm assigning is not null but the compiler thinks it could be.)

```
public static void test(List<String> list = null!) { }
```

3. You can disable nullable reference types for just this piece of the code:

```
#nullable disable
public static void test(List<String> list = null) { }
#nullable restore
```

4. You can disable nullable reference types for the whole file by putting `#nullable disable` at the beginning of it (with your namespace declaration)
5. You can disable nullable reference types for the project. Right click on the project in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Build -> General -> Nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your project file and delete the line that says `<Nullable>Enable</Nullable>`
[image]

Comment: Thanks, as @GSerg point out in official docs, and that I didn't knew of, Null-state analysis and variable annotations are now enabled by default.
So it's time to "use" `?` everywhere needed in .Net 6 and above I guess.

Comment: To me adding the `?` seems like extra work and unhelpful to the code I write, so I just turn off the Null-state analysis warnings. I figured others in my boat might find my answer useful

Comment: Though it will lead to fewer null references exceptions. _(Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake)_

Answer (score 1):

Once Nullable reference types are enabled, `List<T>` is **not nullable** by default.

You have to mark it as nullable explicitly, by appending a `?` character.

```
public static void test(List<String>? list = null)
{ }
```